# Mozilla not resizing images within a predefined div

Tags: html, css, json

This is my first question and I have looked for an answer but can't see anything that has worked, and I have tried a bunch of things already.

We have a huge site that is broken down into a few sections on the home page.  The section that is causing issues it two divs, each 45.5% of the 1100px.  Within each of these are two more divs, each again 45.5% of the half.  We are pulling information from another section of the site using a JSON object to show the latest 2 news articles and 2 latest reviews.  The object is using all the styling I have set up already.

Part of the JSON is the image that gets pulled from the news and reviews. I have used the following CSS to make sure the image is max 160px in height.  All browsers are working fine, but Mozilla is not scaling the images to fit the max width and there is huge overflow.  The image is the set height but it scales the width to that and not to the max-width of 200px.

The CSS is:

```
.review-img {
height: 160px;
width: 200px
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
}
.review-img img {
max-height: 100%; 
max-width: 100%;
}
.news-img {
height: 160px;
width: 200px;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
} 
.news-img img {
max-height: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
 }
```

and the JSON for the news is:

```
    var json_obj = $.parseJSON(headline);//parse JSON
        console.log(json_obj);

        var output = '';

            output+="<div class='one-half'>";
            output+="<div class='news-img'><img alt='' src='http://dealer.mustek.co.za/" + json_obj[0].image +"'/></div>";
            output+="<p><a href='http://dealer.mustek.co.za/view-article.html?p="+ json_obj[0].page_id +"'>" + json_obj[0].article_title + "</a><br>" + json_obj[0].article + "</p>";
            output+="<a href='http://dealer.mustek.co.za/view-article.html?p="+ json_obj[0].page_id +"'>Read more</a>";
             output+="</div>";
             output+="<div class='one-half'>";
            output+="<div class='news-img'><img alt='' src='http://dealer.mustek.co.za/" + json_obj[1].image +"'/></div>";
            output+="<p><a href='http://dealer.mustek.co.za/view-article.html?p="+ json_obj[1].page_id +"'>" + json_obj[1].article_title + "</a><br>" + json_obj[1].article + "</p>";
            output+="<a href='http://dealer.mustek.co.za/view-article.html?p="+ json_obj[1].page_id +"'>Read more</a>";
             output+="</div>";



        $('#newsfeed').html(output);
```

The reviews is exactly the same.

The HTML is:

```
<section class="one-half-feeds">
   <div class="title">
   <h2>Industry News</h2>
   </div>
   <div id="newsfeed"></div>
</section>
<section class="one-half-feeds">
    <div class="title">
   <h2>Tech Reviews</h2>
    </div>
<div id="reviewfeed"></div>
 </section>
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out why all the other browsers are not having an issue at all, but Mozilla just won't work...

Comment: You might want to try changing the img's display to `block` or `inline-block`. Also, you might want to post the output HTML, it makes it easier for the rest of us.

Comment: Just had a look at the site in IE11 (although it is emulating on my Mac through Oracle VirtualBox, and it is even worse, not taking any of the limitations I have set into account.

Comment: I tried to recreate your issue on a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rgin/vhBw9/) . I don't see the problem or rather I'm not understanding it.

Comment: Thanks @rgin! the 'inline-block' seems to have done the trick, and although now the image isn't centre aligned, that I should easily fix. The HTML I posted is the output, the id pulls in from the JSON.

Comment: I'm gonna post as answer in case people might find it useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `display:inline-block` or `display:block` to image style.

```
.review-img img {
    display:inline-block;
    /* etc .. */
}
```